# where does confluent s3 sink put the key?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I setup a confluent s3 sink connect, it stores .avro files in s3.
I dump those files, and find out that they are just the message itself, I don't know where can I find the message key, any idea?

The config is like:

```
{
    "name": "s3-sink-test",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "book",
        "s3.region": "eu-central-1",
        "s3.bucket.name": "kafka",
        "s3.part.size": "5242880",
        "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
        "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.avro.AvroFormat",
        "schema.generator.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.hive.schema.DefaultSchemaGenerator",
        "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner",
        "path.format": "'year'=YYYY/'month'=MM/'day'=dd/'hour'=HH",
        "locale": "US",
        "timezone": "UTC",
        "partition.duration.ms": "3600000",
        "timestamp.extractor": "RecordField",
        "timestamp.field": "local_timestamp",
        "flush.size": "2",
        "schema.compatibility": "NONE"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit** The code has changed to enable this, and the below transform isn't needed - [docs](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-s3-sink/current/index.html#s3-sink-writing-record-keys-headers)

<strike>The Kafka message key is not persevered by any of the storage Kafka Connectors by Confluent out of the box</strike>

Try compiling and setting up the [Archive Transform](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-transform-archive), which can be setup using these properties in the Connect Configuration

```
"transforms" : "Archive",
"transforms.Archive.type" : "com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.archive.Archive"
```

For more about SMTs in Kafka Connect, see [this blog post](https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-3/)

Comment: Is this only suitable for S3? I have Kafka Connect saving message values to an Azure Data Lake and want it to include the keys.

Comment: @SiLaf The Archive Transform works for all connectors. It's only a transform. If you have a specific Azure connector, then you would have to consult the source code of it to see if there is a separate property for adding the keys or not.

Comment: I am trying to use this setup but the setup is flushing only one record per file after applying the transformation. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Piazz That depends on the format.class setting... For example, Avro or Parquet store schemas as part of the file, and two records with different schemas end up in different files... That shouldn't occur if you use JSON

Comment: @OneCricketeer thank you! I ended up compiling a fork of the archive transform which worked good for us: https://github.com/crunchbase/kafka-connect-transform-archive

Comment: @OneCricketeer was the S3 connector code changed? should I use the "Archive" transform or is there an easier way?

Comment: @shlom https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-s3-sink/current/index.html#s3-sink-writing-record-keys-headers

Comment: i added "store.kafka.keys": true,"keys.format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.parquet.ParquetFormat" to my S3 connector but I don't see any change. I don't even see it in the Kafka connect logs, I do see it when checking the connector configs 

Comment: @shlom I've only used the Avro and JSON format classes. It's possible that the Parquet one doesn't write the keys