# Kafka Connect HDFS (Azure) Persist Avro Values AND String Keys

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect

I have configured Kafka Connect HDFS to work on Azure Datalake, however I just noticed that the keys (Strings) are not being persisted in anyway, only the Avro values.

When I think about this I suppose this makes sense as the partitioning I want to apply in the data lake is not related to the key and I have not specified some new Avro Schema which incorporates the key String into the existing Avro value Schema.

Now within the configurations I supply when running the connect-distributed.sh script, I have (among other configurations)

```
...
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://<ip>:<port>
...
```

But within the actual sink connector that I set up using curl I simply specify the output format as

```
...
"format.class": "io.confluent.connect.hdfs.avro.AvroFormat"
...
```

so the connector just assumes that the Avro value is to be written.

So I have two questions. How do I tell the connector that it should save the key along with the value as part of a new Avro schema, and where do I define this schema?

Note that this is an Azure HDInsight cluster and so is not a Confluent Kafka solution (though I would have access to open source Confluent code such as Kafka Connect HDFS)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [where does confluent s3 sink put the key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48598928/where-does-confluent-s3-sink-put-the-key)

Comment: S3 and HDFS connect share the same simlar writer code. The key is also not able to be stored out of the box